# router vpn (pptp) - ipv6

Tags: linux, vpn, router, asus

Есть роутер, к которому можно подключится через pptp. После подключения получаешь белый адрес (адрес роутера).

А можно как-то настроить, что бы получал только ipv6 белый адрес?
 Например, который выберет клиент (сгенерирует) или который ему "даст vpn сервер"

Comment: так уберите выдачу ipv4-адреса и оставьте только выдачу ipv6-адреса.

Comment: А разве так можно сделать? На примере asus роутеров, есть инструкция? Я настройки перерыл - там такого нету

Comment: настройки программы *pppd*, как и в вашем компьютере, находятся в каталоге `/etc/ppp/`. если у вас нет к ним доступа и нет возможности сменить прошивку маршрутизатора на более «дружественную», то ответ на ваш вопрос — **нет**.